# How do I make a nested <div> expand to its contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this system to try to implement a sliding window selector.
I have a `<div>` that is contained in another `<div>`. The outer `<div>` has a fixed size and the inner one should expand to contain its contents.

```
<div style="width: 25px; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="middle">
        <div style="width: 50px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer `<div>` has a fixed size.
The `middle` `<div>` should expand to match the size of the inner `<div>` (the one that has width 50px)
How, using CSS or JavaScript can I ensure that the middle `<div>` is as wide as the inner `<div>`, but still gets cut off by the outer `<div>`?

I have tried to use JQuery to get the length of the inner `<div>` and then dynamically set the width of the middle `<div>`, but this does not consistently get the right length.

Comment: Your `span` can't have a fixed width. Try using another `div`.

Comment: @Blender, sorry the span is full of text that is longer than the outer div. I just used the width to show a quick example.

Comment: Your code should work fine just the way it is, then.

Comment: In fact, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/4F5yc/1/

Comment: @AtesGoral: I changed the question to be clearer. The problem is that the middle <div> should be as wide as the inner one.

Comment: I think this mod of @AtesGoral fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4F5yc/3/) makes the problem clear. You see the innermost green border extends into the hidden overflow area, but the middle blue border stops within the outer div (red border). You want the middle-blue-border to expand to completely enclose the inner-green-border. Is that the gist of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Div elements, by default, try to fit their container. so the middle one will try to fit its container which is the outer div.. it is not affected by content.

If you set the middle one to be `display:inline-block` you make it fit the contents instead of the container it that fixes the issue..

Comment: One more update to the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4F5yc/4/) and setting overflow to scroll so you can see the right-edges of the middle and inner divs, and it's clear that setting middle to `inline-block` as Gaby says makes middle expand to enclose inner, just as chustar asked for. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make inner div float? That way it should display full width of the span but without editing outer div width to expand the content longer than outer div width will be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

divs are block elements, so your inner div will naturally expand to the width of the containing div. You can ensure this by setting the style attribute of the inner div to 100%. You should also set its overflow CSS property to "hidden."

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of the content of any HTML object like this:

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").clientWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` and `max-width: ?px` on `middle`. You'll want to put `overflow-x: hidden` on `middle` (not `outer` like in your code), but I left it off in the demo so you could see the width working.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/hHDQS/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div id="inner1"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="middle">
        <div id="inner2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {    
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}

.middle {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 75px;
    max-width: 300px;
}

#inner1 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

#inner2 {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the inner div can be absolutely positioned the following will stretch it to fill up the parent completely (width and height):

```
#myInner{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```